# Bash/xdotool: Commands work, but not in a script

Tags: bash, terminal, script, window-focus, xdotools

I am making a bash script for Linux which closes the terminal window if the window loses focus.

On the command line, I was able to do this:

```
termwin=$(xdotool getactivewindow)

while : 
do 
  if [[ $(xdotool getactivewindow) != $termwin ]]
  then 
    exit 
  fi 
done
```

It works typed manually into a terminal, but, if I put it into a script, instead of closing the window when focus is lost, the script simply stops.  No error or anything, just back to a prompt.

I feel like I'm missing something basic.

**EDIT**

After reading this...:
[See here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/exit-in-script-files-cause-konsole-terminal-itself-to-exit-801423/)

I tried running this as ". test.sh" rather than "./test.sh" and it worked. The link describes the difference in these methods as running the script as a subprocess or as part of the main process, respectively.  Can anyone just explain this, and/or modify the script to run successfully with "./" instead of ". ", in the latter creates issues?

Comment: shell script debug is my fun, hold on, I shall try to reproduce. I know xdotool its an automate tool.

Comment: My idea is a bit off-topic: do you know about "exotic" window managers? E.g. awesome (http://awesome.naquadah.org/) - you can do this or similar functions easily.

Comment: @uzsolt, you are to? if me, I am mainly on awesome wm quite some years and now and all.

Comment: Yes :) In awesome this is only about 3 lines :) In bash...

Comment: @uzsolt dear, awesome wm has lua, homebrew widgets are candies :), bashlets is another playground :)

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Does `./test.sh && exit` work for you? Just `exit` or `exit 0` when the condition is met in the script, and `exit` will be run in the terminal afterwards.

Comment: Oh bloody hell, that's exactly what I had to do.  I was too absorbed in the script itself to consider running it like that.

Comment: scripting is somehow like building pieces as according to nix philosophy. xdotool is so useful. btw, hug@uzolt

Comment: @uzsolt 2 lines now ;)   cheers.

Comment: @Rony if you calculate the parts of `while` it will about five lines. In awesome: you call a signal function to unfocus, call `c:kill()`, type `end` and that's all. It's three lines. And you shouldn't run a plus bash script which eats your CPU :) So awesome is the winner ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you source the file with `.`, the commands will run just as if you had entered them in the command line. Thus `exit` will exit your currently running shell.

To exit the shell from which the script was executed when forking, you need to get the process id of the parent process. You can try running

```
kill ${PPID}
```

in the script instead of `exit` to kill the parent shell (tip: try just echoing the pid first and check which process it corresponds to so you don't kill your WM or something).

If `${PPID}` doesn't do it for you, you can also try sending the pid as a parameter to the script, but it depends on how and where it's called.

---

You said you used `urxtvd`/`urxvtc`. With that combination, this script kills the terminal from which it was started:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo kill in 3
sleep 3
kill -1 ${PPID}
```

so you should be able to use `kill -1` in this way to kill a single `urxvtc` instance.

Note that if you run this by sourcing, then the `urxvtd` instance will be `$PPID` for the currently running terminal, and *all* terminals will die. You don't want that.

Comment: Dan, the kill PPID method looks good, but fails with my particular terminal.  Im using urxvt in a client/daemon setup (urxvtd and urxvtc).  It seems that each terminal in this case has the same ppid, and s =o this method doesn't work.

What is different is the pty, as found with the tty command.  You can directly tell a pty to do something, right? Something like (not working) "exit >>/dev/pts/0"

Comment: @FruckubusCrunt: Each _terminal_ has the same `PPID` (_parent_ pid), but when you launch a _script_ from a terminal, inside the script the launching _terminal_'s pid will be `PPID`, so it sends the signal to the correct pid. However, `-1` seems to be needed with `urxvtc`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is great Dan, thank you.  A good learning experience for me.  And I certainly could not accept a situation where more terminals would die, as that would defeat the purpose of what I'm doing.  So thanks for the solid explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the script will work as needed:

```
#!/bin/sh

termwin=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
while : ; do
    [ $(xdotool getwindowfocus) = $termwin ] || kill -9 $PPID
done
```

Comment: This yields the sme results for me, it works if typed in manually, and fails

Comment: I am now wondering if "exit" is the problem.  Typed into a terminal, 'exit' closes the terminal, but is it possible that "exit" has a different meaning in a script, that stops the script rather than closing the terminal?  Or is this even possible?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: [Refrain from using `kill -9`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter). A single `kill` is enough, and much nicer. `kill -9` does nothing nice.

Comment: @DanielAndersson thank you very much for your refreshment and very useful link. I use the -9 because my kill does not kill. I shall look into the matter.